# Swagger - system.js:461 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - using @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: spring-data-jpa, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, jpa-2.2

Spring Fox Swagger issue: I have `@ManyToMany` relationship in my JPA model classes, but when launching paginated endpoint getting below error.

```
system.js:461 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Ct (immutable.js:2494)
    at immutable.js:2408
    at ft.Be.withMutations (immutable.js:1353)
    at immutable.js:2405
    at ft.set (immutable.js:2096)
    at It (immutable.js:2780)
    at Mt.set (immutable.js:2686)
    at immutable.js:2651
    at te.__iterate (immutable.js:418)
    at te.forEach (immutable.js:4381)
```

I am using

```
<springfox-swagger-version>2.9.2</springfox-swagger-version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox-swagger-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox-swagger-version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.21</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: super odd, but I have the same issue when I have a single Docket with tag groups. If I move the problematic group to its own Docket, the error goes away...

Comment: I've isolated one part of it to a Docket having a group name with a space in it. If the group name does not have a space, it works as expected... Also it has something in conjunction with specific requests/response. Just haven't figure that out yet. If you post code, that would help.

Comment: @Steve - Could you please show some code or config?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar kind of error with relationships between tables,
As I have a POST api its getting some inputs from a Model class instead of its DTO.

How will it affect is,

- We have the relationship parameter/member variable in that same Model class
- Due to which some time the child model class might be calling the other class and that class will be calling some parent class.
- Ultimately there will be recursion of the call
- That's why this error mainly occurred in my case
  Ex.

  User class --> mapped with UserInfo --> Address --> Addrees containing user Id as mapping. Thus user class is called infinite times.

Solution can be:

- Changing request/response to pure DTO class which does not contain any mapping (bidirectional)
- Only contain minimal Child DTOs
- If needed proper annotation of @JsonBackReference or @JsonManagedReference must be properly used